# Nuances of meaning between "mit ... nehmen" and "mitnehmen"?

Tags: meaning

> Hast du Felix wieder **mit** auf eine deiner Einkaufstouren **genommen**?
>
> Hast du Felix wieder auf eine deiner Einkaufstouren **mitgenommen**?

These two constructions boil down to saying essentially the same thing – except that the first one has *mit* as an adverb while the second uses the separable verb *mitnehmen*.

But do native speakers detect any nuance between the two?

Answer (score 1):

I as a native speaker don't see the slightest difference between the two sentences. And you are wrong in your interpretation of the "mit" in the first example. The verb ist *still* mitgenommen, in germany such verbs are often divided into their components, sometimes you even have to do this to be able to form a valid German sentence.

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised here. I was under the impression that you can separate "nimmt mit" etc but you cannot do the same with the past participle "mitgenommen".

Comment: You cannot *nehmen* a person … well, you can; but it means having sex. There are puns playing around with that reading of *nehmen* and *mitnehmen*.

Comment: @Alone-zee You are right and Torsten is wrong. The past participle of separable verbs is *not* separated. It is also not up to the writer to decide ('often divided'?) if a verb should be separated or not. Either the verb is separable and the prefix *must* be separated from the verb where required, or the verb is *not* separable and the prefix stays with the verb in all positions.

Comment: @jarnbjo Hi. In that case, is "nehmen" the verb used here? I wonder what is the function of "mit" in this sentence, then. Is it an adverb, after all, with the meaning of "(take Felix) **too / as well / with you**"?

Comment: @Alone-zee In your first sentence, 'mit' is an adverb and 'nehmen' is the verb. See also http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mit_neben_damit

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mitnehmen for conjugations of the verb "mitnehmen". Here we have the " Partizip II".
The first of your sentences is wrong and therefore sounds odd to a native speaker. Use the second sentence.